# Rear side of the car was hit - save a few grand and fix it myself?

Tags: honda, repair, accident

A car backed into the back of the car, and the insurance says we are both at fault and therefore owe a few grand for fixes. The worst is that it won't even be able to be repaired until next year. Is there any way I can use some strength and fix it myself? Please post any youtube videos that may help. Thank you so much! Also, can you describe the damage to me? I honestly don't even know how to describe it. Maybe smashed rear bumper? I don't know.
The vehicle is a 2018 Honda Fit[image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Can't repair it until next year? If the insurance company isn't going to pay, why not get it fixed right away? In UK it would be illegal to drive a car in that condition: it would fail a MOT safety test, having protruding bodywork that could cause serious harm to a pedestrian.

Comment: Check out the exhaust also, when I got rear ended, which was not as bad as yours, it buckled  in the right exhaust and muffler. I did not think to check at the time

Comment: Additional to @WeatherVane's comment. In the UK, the police would pull you over with that damage & force you to take the vehicle off road, right there & then. Not only is it a danger to pedestrians, but at speed is quite likely to come right off, once the wind gets behind it. That is an accident waiting to happen.